# Detect drop event on individual objects in kineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

### Main idea

Creating a match the following exercise with the right side dots being draggle and left side dots are the targets.

[image]

Red dots are draggable and are to be dropped on the blue dots.

### Target

Each dot has an associated value with them, furthermore, once a red dot is dropped on a blue dot no other red dot can be placed on the same blue dot.

### Approach

Storing coordinates of each blue dot in an array, and once a red dot is placed closeby a blue dot, the information related to that dot is removed from the array (hence making it invisible).

### Problem

How can I detect a drop event for each red dot, most solutions available online suggest having a `.on` even on the `shape`. However, how should I uniquely identify which one?

### Resource

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLcxchfv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one way to detect red circle drop events and test if they intersect a blue circle.**

- Assign `name:'blue'` when defining every blue circle (kinetic 'name' is like a CSS 'class'):

  `name:'blue'`
- Listen for drag-drops on all red circles:

  `anyRedCircle.on('dragend',function(){});`
- Fetch all the blue circles:

  `stage.find(".blue")`
- Test if this red circle was dropped on one of those blue circles:

  ```
  // fetch all circles with name=='blue' and feed them into a function 
  stage.find(".blue").each(function(b){
      // b is a blue circle
      var dx=this.x()-b.x();
      var dy=this.y()-b.y();
      if(dx*dx+dy*dy<radius*radius){
          // this red circle was dropped on this blue circle
      }
  });
  ```

  });

**Example code and a demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/apdohmcm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var radius=10;
    var $last=$("#lastHit");

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        makeCirclePair(30,i*30+40,150,i*30+40,(i+1)*10);
    }


    function makeCirclePair(redX,redY,blueX,blueY,value){
        var blue=makeCircle(blueX,blueY,'blue',false,value);
        var red=makeCircle(redX,redY,'red',true,0);
        red.on('dragend',function(){
            var red=this;
            var rx=this.x();
            var ry=this.y();
            stage.find(".blue").each(function(b){
                var dx=rx-b.x();
                var dy=ry-b.y();
                if(dx*dx+dy*dy<radius*radius){
                    b.name('gold');
                    b.fill('gold');
                    red.hide();
                    $last.text("Last covered circle had value="+b.value);
                }
            });
            layer.draw();
        });
        red.target=blue;
        var text=new Kinetic.Text({
            x:blueX+20,
            y:blueY-5,
            text:value,
            fill:'black',
        });
        layer.add(text);
        layer.draw();
    }


    function makeCircle(x,y,color,isDraggable,value){
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            name:color,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            radius:radius,
            fill:color,
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth:2,
            draggable:isDraggable
        });
        circle.value=value;
        layer.add(circle);
        return(circle);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id=lastHit>Drag red to blue.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```